# How can I make a Android app look pretty?

Tags: android

When I place things like text boxes they are fixed in one position and I can't move them around easily.

How can I edit the style and maybe put an image at the top of the text boxes and give the app a neat and pretty little layout?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a Relative Layout?

Answer (score 3):

Use RelativeLayouts instead of LinearLayouts (i assume that you are using them) which allow free positioning.

To modify the theme/colors, read [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) graphics and assign them as backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is what you are looking for,but you can arrange the object on the layout from the xml files in res/layouts/ folder.Do not forget to follow the UI guidelines provided by google for android development. Also you can create custom themes for you app if you do not like the default template.